# unlocking bootloader for xperia xa

Tags: fastboot

I want to unlock my bootloader for my sony xperia xa f3113 but when I got to the step where you update the driver on device manager-other devices-S1Boot Fastboot-update driver software and I select the usb_driver folder it says error the hash for the file is not present in the specific catalog file. The file is likey corrupt or the victim of tampering

I followed all the steps from the sony website on how to unlock bootloader but I don't know why it is not working

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You should ask this on a site like XDA (https://www.xda-developers.com/).

Comment: To answer your question, you're not doing anything wrong.  The message tells you exactly what's happening.  There's something wrong with the package file for the driver you're trying to download, so the site isn't allowing you to get it.  You'll either need to wait for that to get fixed or find the driver somewhere else.

Comment: i downloaded the fastboot driver from the sony website and the file was in the instructions on the website but these were posted from 2014

Comment: is there new instructions on how to unlock bootloader for sony xperia xa

Comment: how do i check what os im running on my computer